# Update one observableCollection from other collection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I need to update one observablecollection from another one as in below example:

Update ObservableCollection A with Data in Collection B:

```
ObservableCollection<Category> A = new ObservableCollection<Category>()
{
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 1, 
        Name = ABC
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 4, 
        Name = UVW
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 2, 
        Name = DEF
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 3, 
        Name = XYZ
      }
}

ObservableCollection<Category> B = new ObservableCollection<Category>()
{
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 1, 
        Name = ABC
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 5, 
        Name = LMN
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 7, 
        Name = GHI
      },
  new Category()
      {
        ID = 3, 
        Name = XYZ
      }
}
```

After updating ObservableCollection A it should contain same data as B, Since I have binded this list to the UI List element i don't want it to clear and then Add all the elements one by one it would look odd in User Experience. So is there any optimized LINQ to just iterate through all the Elements in two Collection and update List A with element of List B

Comment: Update A Like this will Update entire list since its binded and data may be huge in both the list that causes UI to hang a little bit. That is why I am adding each item at a time after binding the collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign values from one list to another using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708266/assign-values-from-one-list-to-another-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to `A`'s collection changes. I've based the following implementation on the statements from [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html). I cannot ensure it's operational in it's full extent as I was rather reluctant testing every possible collection manipulation.

Subscribe to `A`'s changes (after you instantiate it):

```
A.CollectionChanged += A_CollectionChanged;
```

Perform synchronization actions on `B`:

```
private void A_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            //If index is defined; insert.
            if (e.NewStartingIndex >= 0)
            {
                var index = e.NewStartingIndex;
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    B.Insert(index, item as Category);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            //Else; add.
            else
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    B.Add(item as Category);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            //Remove old items at old index first.
            var oldIndex = e.OldStartingIndex;
            for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
            {
                B.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
                oldIndex++;
            }
            //Then add new items at new index.
            var newIndex = e.NewStartingIndex;
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                B.RemoveAt(newIndex);
                newIndex++;
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            //If remove index is defined; remove at index (safe in case item reference appears in collection multiple times)
            if (e.OldStartingIndex >= 0)
            {
                var index = e.OldStartingIndex;
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    B.RemoveAt(index);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            //Else remove item.
            else
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    B.Remove(item as Category);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            //If replace index is defined.
            if (e.NewStartingIndex >= 0)
            {
                var index = e.NewStartingIndex;
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    B[index] = item as Category;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            //Else try to find index.
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    var index = B.IndexOf(e.OldItems[i] as Category);
                    B[index] = e.NewItems[i] as Category;
                }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            //Reset collection.
            B.Clear();
            foreach (var item in sender as ObservableCollection<Category>)
                B.Add(item);
            break;
    }
}
```