# Update a property field in a List

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Map>` and I wanted to update the `Map.Target` property based from a matching value from another `List<Map>`.

Basically, the logic is:

```
If mapsList1.Name is equal to mapsList2.Name
    Then mapsList1.Target = mapsList2.Name
```

The structure of the `Map` class looks like this:

```
public class Map {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following but obviously it's not working:

```
List<Map> mapsList1 = new List<Map>();
List<Map> mapsList2 = new List<Map>();
    
// populate the 2 lists here
    
mapsList1.Where(m1 => mapsList2.Where(m2 =>  m1.Name == m2.Name) ) // don't know what to do next
```

The count of items in list 1 will be always greater than or equal to the count of items in list 2. No duplicates in both lists.

Comment: Personally I would just turn the second map into dictionary and iterate through the first collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign values from one list to another using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708266/assign-values-from-one-list-to-another-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are a small number of items in the lists and only one item in list 1 that matches:

```
list2.ForEach(l2m => list1.First(l1m => l1m.Name == l2m.Name).Target = l2m.Target);
```

If there are more than one item in List1 that must be updated, enumerate the entire list1 doing a First on list2.

```
list1.ForEach(l1m => l1m.Target = list2.FirstOrDefault(l2m => l1.Name == l2m.Name)?.Target ?? l1m.Target);
```

If there are a large number of items in list2, turn it into a dictionary

```
var d = list2.ToDictionary(m => m.Name);
list1.ForEach(m => m.Target = d.ContainsKey(m.Name) ? d[m.Name].Target : m.Target);
```

(Presumably list2 doesn't contain any repeated names)

If list1's names are unique and everything in list2 is in list1, you could even turn list1 into a dictionary and enumerate list2:

```
var d=list1.ToDictionary(m => m.Name);
list2.ForEach(m => d[m.Name].Target = m.Target);
```

If List 2 has entries that are not in list1 or list1 has duplicate names, you could use a Lookup instead, you'd just have to do something to avoid a "collection was modified; enumeration may not execute" you'd get if you were trying to modify the list it returns in response to a name

> mapsList1.Where(m1 => mapsList2.Where(m2 =>  m1.Name == m2.Name) ) // don't know what to do next

LINQ Where doesn't really work like that / that's not a statement in itself. The m1 is the entry from list1, and the inner Where would produce an enumerable of list 2 items, but it doesn't result in the Boolean the outer Where is expecting, nor can you do anything to either of the sequences because LINQ operations are not supposed to have side effects. The only thing you can do with a Where is capture or use the sequence it returns in some other operation (like enumerating it), so Where isn't really something you'd use for this operation unless you use it to find all the objects you need to alter. It's probably worth pointing out that ForEach is a list thing, not a LINQ thing, and is basically just another way of writing `foreach(var item in someList)`

Comment: items in list 1 will be always equal or greater than the items in list 2

Comment: Welcome! Roughly how many items are there in list1 and list 2?

Comment: each list could have max 1,048,576. List 1 will never have a duplicate.

Comment: Subject to the caveats mentioned (no duplicates in Name) i'd definitely turn list1 into a dictionary and enumerate list2. If list2 isn't a perfect subset (i.e. it might contain an item not rpesent in list1) then you'll need a ContainsKey or TryGetValue to avoid exceptions; let me know if you need some pointer on it

Comment: ok, will do it. thank you again, appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

If collections are big enough better approach would be to create a dictionary to lookup the targets:

```
List<Map> mapsList1 = new List<Map>();
List<Map> mapsList2 = new List<Map>();
var dict = mapsList2
    .GroupBy(map => map.Name)
    .ToDictionary(maps => maps.Key, maps => maps.First().Target);
foreach (var map in mapsList1)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(map.Name, out var target))
    {
        map.Target = target;
    }
}
```

Note, that this will discard any possible name duplicates from `mapsList2`.