# Check condition and assign value with two list using lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach(var statusDetail in statusDetails)
{
   foreach(var status in statuses)
   {
       if (statusDetail.Id == status.Id)
       {
          statusDetail.Name=status.Name;
       }
   }
}
```

Where statusDetails and statuses are list.

Can someone help me to convert this in linq lambda expression. I tried all the possible ways but I get stuck every time.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this one I've just finished answering.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168531/update-a-property-field-in-a-list/68168598?noredirect=1#comment120480317_68168598

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Why do you want it converted to LINQ? It won't buy you any readability advantage over this much more simpler version.

Comment: Just reduce the line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
statusDetails.ForEach(statusDetail => statusDetail.Name = statuses.FirstOrDefault(status => status.Id == statusDetail.Id)?.Name ?? statusDetail.Name);
```

But the result is not exactly the same if there are more matching elements in statuses. But I assumed you want the first matching element, otherwise you need to use LastOrDefault() instead of FirstOrDefault()

Comment: This code is not equivalent to the code in the question

Comment: The problem with this code is, that when the Id's don't match, you're assigning the Default value to the name. The code in the question leaves the Name as it was before when the id isn't found.

Comment: A small fix with coalesce at the end should fix what @JeroenvanLangen points to: `statusDetails.ForEach(statusDetail => statusDetail.Name = statuses.FirstOrDefault(status => status.Id == statusDetail.Id)?.Name ?? statusDetail.Name);`

Comment: Thank's @RoarS. I adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: @PankajMoriya: If you're satisfied with this answer, please accept it in order to close this issue. BR

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick support