# Why is it taking so long to loop through Excel cells and compare values?

Tags: c#, excel

I am eventually trying to imitate the Excel formula SUMIF with just loops because the requirements of my project prevent me from using Excel formulas.

I'm stuck at this early step of trying to find all the places that the values of each row of a column in Sheet1Rows have a match in the rows of a column in sheet2.

```
//numSheet1Rows ~= 18000
//numSheet2Rows ~= 110500

 for (int counterC = 2; counterC < numMathRows + 2; ++counterC)
 {
    for (int counterG = 2; counterG <= numPLMRows + 2; ++counterG)
    {                       
        if (sheet1.Cells[counterG, 7].Value == sheet2.Cells[counterC, 1].Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("row " + counterG + " is a match.");
        }                    
    }

 }
```

This code works, but is much much too slow. It takes almost 20 minutes to compare one item in sheet1 to every item in sheet2.

Can anyone tell me why this is taking so long?
Is it just because there are so many items I'm trying to compare?
If so, would it be better for me to use something besides Excel to do this comparison?

Comment: Maybe try constructing lists of the excel values (single pass over each sheet to get the values), and then use those lists to compare the values?  The theory is that the interop is introducing an extra amount of time, which may or may not be the case..  Just a thought.

Comment: Because you are executing it via interop *and* it is out-of-process. For big loops it will be much faster in VBA directly in Excel

Comment: *If so, would it be better for me to use something besides Excel to do this comparison?* - yes. Load the datas into a pair of C# hashsets and intersect them, or hashset one and iterate the other list performing lookups. I'd be surprised if it takes more than a few seconds to answer. Nested loops (Omn) of hundreds of thousands of values to excel interop  is pure madness

Comment: ps; see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168531/update-a-property-field-in-a-list/68168598#68168598 - pps; the posted code doesn't look like a sumif to me; sumif accumulates some "columntosum" if the entry in "somecolumn" is equal to some value. For that in c# you'd probably do `collection.Sum(x => x.someproperty==value?x.propertytosum:0)` or if you're doing it for a lot of values, `collection.GroupBy(x=>x.somecolumn).Select(g => new{g.Key, S=g.Sum(gg => gg.propertytosum))`